# How can I put multiple commands in cloud9 runner?

Tags: python, virtualenv, cloud9-ide

I want to create a runner to activate a virtualenv and run python code in it.
Below configuration doesn't work:

```
// Create a custom Cloud9 runner - similar to the Sublime build system
// For more information see https://docs.c9.io/custom_runners.html
{
   "cmd" : ["source /home/p2/bin/activate && python", "$file", "$args"],
   "info" : "Started $project_path$file_name",
   "env" : {},
   "selector" : "*\.py"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution :)

```
// Create a custom Cloud9 runner - similar to the Sublime build system
// For more information see https://docs.c9.io/custom_runners.html
{
    "cmd" : ["/home/p2/bin/python", "$file", "$args"],
    "info" : "Started $project_path$file_name",
    "env" : {},
    "selector" : "^*\\.py$"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also pipe the command through bash -c